# Arduino & EtherCard library - Print website contents to serial

Tags: c, arduino

I'm pretty new to this stuff, but I'd like to have a simple example of how to print website contents to the serial monitor using the EtherCard library. By the way, is there already some documentation on it? My purpose is to get a JSON string and control some leds with it via a website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Arduino IDE, click on file, then examples, then Ethernet, there is an example named Webclient that does just what you are asking.

You will have to put the ip address of the server you're looking for in the program, as well as the ip of the arduino and the mac address as well.